# how to undelete files without umounting the filesystem and directly into that filesystem?

Tags: ext4, extundelete

ext4, extundelete needs fs umounted right? and would restore to another fs, that wont work for me.

The deleted are big files, if umounting and restoring on another filesystem I would have to copy back to the original fs.

So, I wonder if there is some way to just restore on the mounted filesystem, and to the mounted fs. I read there could have a way to "re-link" the deleted files, but we would need to know the deleted inode, and nothing is listed by `debugfs -w`. Any other idea?

Actually I dont really need to keep it mounted, just that the files are restored direcly on the same FS, if it could be done umounted would work too.

Edit: by what I  read here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/266107/30352 it is impossible with ext4!

Comment: Have you checked `lsof`? If you are lucky, some processes still have the files open. And of course you may just copy the whole FS to some external drive and do the restoration there. Are you aware of the danger that a mounted FS might overwrite the files sooner or later?

Comment: They are not very important, they are just big. I have already rebooted once, but this `lsof` tip may be useful one day, thx!